# How to Insert Self-Hosted Video in WordPress Post

Tags: videos

Does WordPress have an easy way to insert video in a post? I am not referring to YouTube, Vimeo or other hosting sites, just video I upload myself on the server or through the Media manager. I have an mp4 video for example, and I'd like to have it play within the post, it's hosted on the same server as the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML 5

```
<video width="640" height="360" src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/my_video.mp4" autobuffer>
    <div class="fallback">
        <p>You must have an HTML5 capable browser.</p>
    </div>
</video>
```

For Flash

Check out [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/)